# Build an auto completion service with one or multiple search terms

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete

I am building an auto completion feature for my mobile app. The results need to come from my web service built on Laravel 5.8.

api.php:

```
Route::get('locations/autocomplete', 'LocationsController@autocomplete');
```

LocationsController:

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
    $locations = Location::query();
    foreach($request->words as $word) {
        $locations->whereRaw('country_name LIKE ? OR state_name LIKE ? OR city_name LIKE ? ', ['%'.$word.'%','%'.$word.'%','%'.$word.'%']);
    } 
    $locations = $locations->distinct()->paginate(10);

    return AutoCompleteLocationResource::collection($locations);
}
```

When I do a GET request to `localhost:8000/api/locations/autocomplete?words[]=united&words[]=atlanta`, it gives me a result as if I wrote it using `$locations->orWhereRaw`:

```
select * from locations where 
country_name LIKE %united% OR state_name LIKE %united% OR city_name LIKE %united% 
AND 
country_name LIKE %atlanta% OR state_name LIKE %atlanta% OR city_name LIKE %atlanta%
```

What I want is to logically separate the two blocks with an AND like so:

```
select * from locations where 
(country_name LIKE %united% OR state_name LIKE %united% OR city_name LIKE %united%)
AND 
(country_name LIKE %atlanta% OR state_name LIKE %atlanta% OR city_name LIKE %atlanta%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, multiple calls to `whereRaw` does not logically separate each query. You have to do it manually.

This is what solved the problem.

```
$locations->whereRaw('(country_name LIKE ? OR state_name LIKE ? OR city_name LIKE ? )', ['%'.$word.'%','%'.$word.'%','%'.$word.'%']);
```

Notice the extra '(' and ')' characters at the start and end of the first parameter for `whereRaw`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
$query = Location::query();

foreach($request->words as $word) {
   $query->where(function($qry) use ($word)  {
       $qry->where('country_name', 'like', '%'.$word.'%');
       $qry->orWhere('state_name', 'like', '%'.$word.'%');
       $qry->orWhere('city_name', 'like', '%'.$word.'%');
   });
}

$locations = $query->distinct()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: so this is called parameter grouping. thanks! https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: No problem, glad to help.